# How to increase a number in a text file by one and write it back to the file?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a number from a txt file. then increase it by 1 then write that number to the file but it just empties the file.

How do I fix this?

Code:

```
f = open('BestillingNr.txt', 'r')
bestillingNr = int(f.read())
bestillingNr += 1

f2 = open('BestillingNr.txt', 'w')
f2.write(f'{str(bestillingNr)}')

f.close()
f2.close
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the second file. You were missing the () at the end of `f2.close` so the close method actually won't have been executed.

In the example below, I am using `with` which creates a context manager to automatically close the file.

```
with open('BestillingNr.txt', 'r') as f:
    bestillingNr = int(f.read())

bestillingNr += 1

with open('BestillingNr.txt', 'w') as f2:    
    f2.write(f'{str(bestillingNr)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

after this line `f2.write(f'{str(bestillingNr)}')`, you should add flush command `f2.flush()`

This code is work well:

```
f = open('BestillingNr.txt', 'r')
bestillingNr = int(f.read())
f.close()
bestillingNr += 1

f2 = open('BestillingNr.txt', 'w')
f2.write(f'{str(bestillingNr)}')
f2.flush()
f2.close()
```

Comment: `flush` here is useless, everything that would need to be flushed will be when the file gets closed. Also, note that the good practice in Python is to use context managers, see the other answer for an example.